# Highlight multiple words in a string using SpannableString

Tags: android, underline, spannablestring

I'm using a `SpannableString` to underline certain words, however, I realized the code I have only highlights the first word if there are multiple words.  Not exactly sure how to accomplish highlighting multiple words:

```
String keyword = "test";
String text = "This is a test to underline the three test words in this test";

SpannableString output = new SpannableString(text);

if (text.indexOf(keyword) > -1)
{
    int keywordIndex = text.indexOf(keyword);
    int keywordLength = keyword.length();

    int start = keywordIndex;
    int end = keywordIndex + (keywordLength);                   

    output.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), start, end, 0);
}
```

I was thinking I could `split` the text at every space and loop through it, but wasn't sure if there was a better way.

I do have this code to highlight multiple words using a regular expression, however, I'm try to avoid regular expressions since it's in an Android app and I'm using it in a `ListView` and I'm told they are very expensive.  Also this code I have only highlight whole words, so using the example text above, if the word "protest" was in the sentence, it wouldn't get highlighted using this code:

```
 Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:test")\\b").matcher(text);

while (matcher.find())
{
  output.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0);
}
```

Comment: Use java's regular expressions for multiple matches.

Comment: @Singularity I've updated my OP. I do have code using regular expressions, but I'm told regex are very expensive, especially on a mobile device.

Comment: Depends on length of your text. In what context you are using "expensive" ? CPU usage or `ListView`'s responsiveness ?

Comment: CPU usage.  The strings for the `ListView` are pretty small, mostly news headlines, so maybe it's not a big deal?